# I have a website which contains textbox, the data entered in the text box should be imported to database

Tags: php, html

I have created database named idea and table named `user_tndrequest` and the connection part is also done, I have done the following coding part, but when I enter any text in the text box, the output after clicking on the submit button results in an error, please help me with this.

```
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<html>
    <h2 align="center"> TND REQUEST </h2>
    <h3 align="center">
        <form method="post"  action="database2.php">
            <p><textarea name="inputtxt" cols=40 rows=8></textarea></p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            <p align="center"><a href="index.php">logout</a></p>
        </form>
    </h3>
</body >
```

Code for database2:

```
<?php
    define('db_name','idea');
    define('db_user','root');
    define('db_password','');
    define('db_host','localhost');    

    $link=mysql_connect(db_host,db_user,db_password);

    if (!$link)
    {
        die('couldnot connetc:'.mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected=mysql_select_db(db_name,$link);
    if (!$db_selected)
    {
        die('cant connect to db');
    }

    $value=$_POST['inputtxt'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_tndrequest (inputtxt) VALUES ('$value')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        die('error');
        # code...
    }

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_user, db_password, 'inputtxt');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_tndrequest";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    //echo var_dump($result);
    $temp = 0;
    $colour = "blue";
    $array_len = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //echo $array_len;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($temp == $array_len - 1) {              

        echo '<p>'.'<center>'.'<font face="Helvetica">'.'<font size="7">' .  $row['inputtxt'] .'</font>'. '</font>'.'</center>' . '</p>';
        }
        $temp++;
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to the database twice? And moreover, this code needs lot improvement. I believe, you are trying this for learning purpose.

Comment: u r telling about the database2.php file??

Comment: First of all, you should use mysqli_ instead of mysql_

Comment: yes,two times im connecting,because once for the text to get into database,when i enter text in box and the other time for displaying the text as output.

Comment: @sasi: You don't need to connect twice for that. This is too broad to be explained here. You should refer tutorials online.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\database2.php on line 15
cant connect to db...this error im getting after changing it to mysqli

Comment: @Bhavik Shah: can u suggest me some websites for this?